# Speed up insert new data to PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, postgresql-performance

My current workflow is as follows.

However, it is extremely slow. It only can handle millions of data per/day

I want to speed it up. Any idea?

## query_expression (generated by Ruby rake file, then put the generated SQL expression into `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute`)

- Step 1 of `sample-1-query.sql` : Aggregate data by minute, hour, ...

  ```
      LEFT JOIN
      (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ON (1)
          date_trunc('#{frequence}', ticktime) AS ticktime ,
  ```
- Step 2 of `sample-1-query.sql` : Filling the empty/gap

  ```
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series
        (
          date_trunc('second', min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP),
          max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP,
  ```
- query_expression

  ```
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (time)
         time_series.ticktime AS time,
         t.high,
         t.low,
         t.open,
         t.close,
         t.volume,
         t.product_type,
         t.contract_month
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) generate_series
        (
          date_trunc('second', min(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP),
          max(ticktime)::TIMESTAMP,
          '1 #{frequence}'::interval
        ) AS ticktime FROM #{market} WHERE product_type ='#{product_type}' AND contract_month = '#{contract_month}'::timestamp

      ) time_series
      LEFT JOIN
      (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ON (1)
          date_trunc('#{frequence}', ticktime) AS ticktime ,
          first_value(last_price) OVER w AS open,
          max(last_price) OVER w AS high ,
          min(last_price) OVER w AS low,
          last_value(last_price)  OVER w AS close,
          sum(last_volume) OVER w AS volume,
          product_type,
          contract_month
          FROM #{market}
          WHERE product_type ='#{product_type}' 
          AND contract_month = '#{contract_month}'::timestamp
          WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('#{frequence}', ticktime) ORDER BY ticktime
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                       AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
      ) t USING (ticktime)
      WHERE time_series.ticktime::time >= '#{market_begin_end_time[market]["begin_at"]}'::time 
      AND time_series.ticktime::time < '#{market_begin_end_time[market]["end_at"]}'::time
      AND time_series.ticktime > '#{sampling_begin_time}'::TIMESTAMP 
      ORDER BY 1
  ```

Then

## Rake file

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query_expression).each_with_index do |raw_record, j|
     Model.create(raw_record)                     
end
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know `ruby-on-rails` language, but i'm sure that concerning performance, you have to bring your PostgreSQL version and an [`explain`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) to diagnistic !

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. There is a data window but no window function; a join condition but no join. Provide the query you are actually using, add some explanation what it's supposed to do, the table definition and your version of Postgres. Read the tag info of [`[postgresl-performance]`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter it seems that the quwstion isn't about postgres performance, but about rails performance

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: To handle millions of rows or more with a query similar to the presented fragments, optimizing the query performance must be top priority.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter the text provided says that it he requires just reform the plain SQL to arel/rails sql text